# Xcode Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _APMUserDataFieldEmailAddress... Flutter project

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm getting this error whenever I try to compile or generate an IPA to send it to the App store.

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-07-08 23:02:28.807 xcodebuild[15110:809520] [MT] DVTSDK:             Warning: SDK path collision for path '<DVTFilePath:0x6000023b9030:'/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk'>': SDK with name 'macosx13.0' being superseded by SDK with 'macosx13.0'.
2022-07-08 23:02:31.110 xcodebuild[15110:809520] warning:  The file reference for "GoogleAppMeasurement-xcframeworks.sh" is a member of multiple groups ("Support Files" and "Support Files"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
2022-07-08 23:02:31.110 xcodebuild[15110:809520] warning:  The file reference for "GoogleAppMeasurement.debug.xcconfig" is a member of multiple groups ("Support Files" and "Support Files"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
2022-07-08 23:02:31.110 xcodebuild[15110:809520] warning:  The file reference for "GoogleAppMeasurement.release.xcconfig" is a member of multiple groups ("Support Files" and "Support Files"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
2022-07-08 23:02:32.943 xcodebuild[15110:809671] nil host used in call to allowsSpecificHTTPSCertificateForHost
2022-07-08 23:02:32.943 xcodebuild[15110:809671] nil host used in call to allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:
** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
    /var/folders/ll/gjdf4jj56nd5bvg06lknywl80000gn/T/flutter_tools.wqDSaC/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirM4nhPd/temporary_xcresult_bundle

/Users/chancilson/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler_apple-9.0.4/ios/Classes/strategies/PhonePermissionStrategy.m:50:35: warning: 'subscriberCellularProvider' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    CTCarrier *carrier = [netInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                  serviceSubscriberCellularProviders
In module 'CoreTelephony' imported from /Users/chancilson/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler_apple-9.0.4/ios/Classes/strategies/PhonePermissionStrategy.m:8:
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Headers/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h:114:50: note: property 'subscriberCellularProvider' is declared deprecated here
@property(readonly, retain, nullable) CTCarrier *subscriberCellularProvider API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("serviceSubscriberCellularProviders", ios(4.0, 12.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(macos);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same bug and I noticed that after doing `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, then `flutter build ios`; it removes my team account in "Signing and Capabilities" in Pods.xcodeproj (as seen in the picture) ... I'm not sure why this happens but what I do now is that I re-add my team again, then straight to `flutter build ios` then it works.

[image: xcode screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Clear the derived data folder and rebuild. Usually this is a caching issue

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have not included permission in info.plist

here is the link to the package [permission_hanlder](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) and read the setup guide and include all the necessary permission.

Comment: Of course I have it included!